# Run multiple jobs in parallel in Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I would like to run multiple jobs in parallel on the same automation server.  For this I need as many agents installed as the number of parallel jobs.

When I try to install an additional remote agent the installer picks the location of the first agent that is already installed on the automation server. As a result the installation fails.

What I did was: I turned off the first agent and then I run the installer for the new remote agent.

How should I go about installing an addition remote agent?

Regards,

Archie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> location of the first agent

I presume you're referring to the agent's home dir. Try overriding it per agent with a distinct location using:

```
-Dbamboo.home=/opt/bambooX
```

More info: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/additional-remote-agent-options-436044733.html